# Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have downloaded the SDL Library, i created an Xcode project, but when i try to build the xcode return this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SDL_CreateMutex", referenced from:
      -[testViewController packet_queue_init:] in testViewController.o
  "_SDL_CreateCond", referenced from:
      -[testViewController packet_queue_init:] in testViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

how can i fix it??

thanks

Comment: iphone is not x86. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture

Comment: Where did you download the SDL library? It sounds as if it wasn't compiled for the iPhone simulator.

Comment: the SDL library i have downloaded at -> hg clone http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL sdl-1.3

Comment: i have clean the project, and now the error is :

    Check dependencies
    
    [BEROR]No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=i386, VALID_ARCHS=armv6 armv7).


any idea??
thanks

Comment: I still don't understand what file you have downloaded. The pasted links leads to a page with hundreds of links. Are you using an already compiled, binary library, or did you compile the library yourself?

Comment: I use the library pre compiled, but the problem isn't the library! The problem is the headers file in the ./SDL subdirectory!

Answer (score 0):

Keeps happening to me randomly too. Assuming you're still using your project, just try to toggle the options for the following settings :

- Build active architecture only (DEBUG is usually YES, RELEASE is usually NO).
- SDK : Latest
- Build target: iPhone OS 4.0 (Or whatever your min supported OS is)

Comment: In one of my projects I do not have "Build active architecture only" line.  Do you know how to add it?